# Cypress foreach loop stop condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, cypress, cypress-each

I need some help with the following loop:

```
 localStorage.removeItem('DDFound');

 cy.get(sel).each(($el, index, $list) => {
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('DDFound')!='1')
    {      
    cy.log(localStorage.getItem('DDFound'));
    cy.wrap($el).click().then(()=> {
      cy.get(table).then(elx => {
            if(elx.find(tableitem).length > 0) {
                cy.get(tableitem).click();
                cy.get(lable).should('contain.text',"Item")
                localStorage.setItem('DDFound','1');                  
            }
            
        })
    });
    }
});
```

I would like to break just after finding the right item(tableitem) and for that, I'm setting a localstorage (didn't find any other way) but it looks like cypress runs all items in each loop in parallel and not getting to the `if(localStorage.getItem('DDFound')!='1')` after each element.

Answer (score 0):

[You can stop the `.each()` loop early by returning false in the callback function.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Return-early) In your case, we can just return the value if `DDItem` does not equal one.

```js
 localStorage.removeItem('DDFound');

 cy.get(sel).each(($el, index, $list) => {
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('DDFound')!='1')
    {      
    cy.log(localStorage.getItem('DDFound'));
    cy.wrap($el).click().then(()=> {
      cy.get(table).then(elx => {
            if(elx.find(tableitem).length > 0) {
                cy.get(tableitem).click();
                cy.get(lable).should('contain.text',"Item")
                localStorage.setItem('DDFound','1');                  
            }
            
        })
    });
    }

    return localStorage.getItem('DDFound') !== 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have complex code inside the `.each()` you should wrap it in a promise

```js
let found = false;

cy.get(sel).each(($el, index, $list) => {
    
  if (found) return false;   // early exit

  return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {

    cy.wrap($el).click().then(() => {
      cy.get(table).then(elx => {
        if (elx.find(tableitem).length > 0) {
          cy.get(tableitem).click();
          cy.get(label).should('contain.text',"Item")
          found = true;
        }
        resolve()      // wait for above to complete
      })
    })

  })
})
```

See [.each() - Promises](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Promises)

> **Promises are awaited**
>
> If your callback function returns a Promise, it will be awaited before iterating over the next element in the collection.